# Initializing a new vector3 with field values instead of literals

Tags: c#, vector

this is actually my first time using C#. So I am trying to make a new vector3 consisting of the following variables but that does not seem to work. After googling, I believe the error is due to early binding in C3. Besides using numbers instead of variables when creating a new vector3, how would I fix this? (if possible). Thanks in advance. I am using Unity's MonoDevelop by the way.

```
private int crest1=14;
private int starter=3;
private Vector3 L1=new Vector3(crest1,starter,crest1); //error here
```

---

```
private float crest1=14;
private float starter=3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in field declaration.   You should probably do it in the constructor.

eg:

```
class MyClass
{
    private float crest1 = 14;
    private float starter = 3;
    private Vector3 L1;

    public MyClass()
    {
        L1 = new Vector3(crest1, starter, crest1);
    }
}
```